# Export to PDF problem

Tags: reportingservices-2005

HI,

I have a SSRS report that has about 4 tables in the body and each one has about 4 columns,
I fill each tale with its related data, my problem is when export to EXCEL everything is fine but when export to PDF it seems that tables are overlapping each other in away that makes the report look bad.

does any one have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Try placing each of the tables in a Rectangle, ensuring that the rectangles of of the same height and width. To further ensure that there is no overlapping, place a Line object between each table. A bit of a hack, but it should work.